# Trying to implement a charge in stripe api after form submission

Tags: php, forms, stripe-payments

I have succesfully submitted a form to the stripe api and see it in my logs, now i need to do a charge on the server in php. My main issue is order of operations I have include the stripe php library in a folder called stripe and containing the stripe.php file located at the bottom

Here is my code.

/// charge.php

```
<?php
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account
Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_random");

// Get the credit card details submitted by the form
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

// Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
try {
  $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => 1000, // amount in cents, again
    "currency" => "cad",
    "card" => $token,
    "description" => "payinguser@example.com")
  );
} catch(Stripe_CardError $e) {
  // The card has been declined
}

?>
```

form.php

```
<form action="charge.php" method="POST" id="payment-form">
            <span class="payment-errors"></span>

            <div class="form-row">
              <label>
                <span>Card Number</span>
                <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
              </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
              <label>
                <span>CVC</span>
                <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>
              </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
              <label>
                <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</span>
                <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month"/>
              </label>
              <span> / </span>
              <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year"/>
            </div>

            <button type="submit">Submit Payment</button>
          </form>
```

payment.js

```
Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_random');


jQuery(function($) {
  $('#payment-form').submit(function(event) {
    var $form = $(this);

    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

    // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
    return false;
  });
});

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
  var $form = $('#payment-form');

  if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    // response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
    // and submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};
```

stripe.php

```
<?php

echo "Running the Stripe PHP bindings test suite.\n".
     "If you're trying to use the Stripe PHP bindings you'll probably want ".
     "to require('lib/Stripe.php'); instead of this file\n";

$testURI = '/simpletest/autorun.php';
$ok = @include_once(dirname(__FILE__).$testURI);
if (!$ok) {
  $ok = @include_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../vendor/simpletest'.$testURI);
}
if (!$ok) {
  echo "MISSING DEPENDENCY: The Stripe API test cases depend on SimpleTest. ".
       "Download it at <http://www.simpletest.org/>, and either install it ".
       "in your PHP include_path or put it in the test/ directory.\n";
  exit(1);
}

// Throw an exception on any error
// @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
  throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
}
// @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd
set_error_handler('exception_error_handler');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../lib/Stripe.php');

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Stripe/TestCase.php');

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Stripe/ApiRequestorTest.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Stripe/AuthenticationErrorTest.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Stripe/CardErrorTest.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Stripe/AccountTest.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Stripe/BalanceTest.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Stripe/BalanceTransactionTest.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Stripe/ChargeTest.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Stripe/CouponTest.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Stripe/CustomerTest.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Stripe/DiscountTest.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Stripe/Error.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Stripe/InvalidRequestErrorTest.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Stripe/InvoiceTest.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Stripe/ObjectTest.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Stripe/PlanTest.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Stripe/SubscriptionTest.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Stripe/Token.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Stripe/TransferTest.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Stripe/RecipientTest.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Stripe/RefundTest.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Stripe/ApplicationFeeTest.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Stripe/ApplicationFeeRefundTest.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/Stripe/UtilTest.php');
```

Comment: Im not sure exactly where you are confused... you would include the `lib/Stripe.php` in the `charge.php` file at the top and then do your work with the API based on the data you are posting to `charge.php`. Also please not that the stripe file you have put in your question **IS NOT** the one you should be including in `charge.php` as noted in the comment. The file you have shown looks like it is the testsuite runner.

Comment: Thankyou that plus putting errors on in mamp helped. Im not a big php guy so thats probably where the confusion lied. Do you want to make this a answer so i can choose it.